# what is the issue in one line if else statement

Tags: javascript

what is the difference between these two piece of coding ? one is working and one is not working as it should .. (this is working)

```
function classchange(e) {
      var elems = document.querySelector(".active");
      if (elems !== null) {
        elems.classList.remove("active");   
      }
      this.querySelector("a").classList.add("active");          
    }
```

(this is not working)

```
function classchange(e) {
      var elems = document.querySelector(".active");
      (elems !== null) ? elems.classList.remove("active") : this.querySelector("a").classList.add("active")
}
```

although i think these two piece of codes do the same thing .

Comment: In the first example, both expressions will be evaluated if `elems !== null`. In the second example it's always one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

> i think these two piece of codes do the same thing

They don't.  In the first one, this line always executes:

```
this.querySelector("a").classList.add("active");
```

In the second one it only executes when the condition is `false`.

**But more importantly...** This is a common misconception, but the ternary conditional operator **is not** a replacement for an if/else structure.  It's for conditionally producing a value, not for conditionally executing blocks of code.  If you want to conditionally execute a block of code, use an `if` statement.  The first example above (the one that "works") is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not an if-else statement. It is just if. The second is an if-else statement. So both codes are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In this form the second case (which is using the [conditional or also known as the ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)) is equal to this:

```
function classchange(e) {
  var elems = document.querySelector(".active");
  if(elems !== null) 
    elems.classList.remove("active") 
  else  // <-- notice the else here
    this.querySelector("a").classList.add("active")
}
```

Ternary operator syntax is: `condition ? expression If True : expression If False`

as you can see this is clearly different than:

```
function classchange(e) {
  var elems = document.querySelector(".active");
  if (elems !== null) {
    elems.classList.remove("active");   
  }  // <-- no else here
  this.querySelector("a").classList.add("active");          
}
```

Where there is no `else` and we end up executing `this.querySelector("a").classList.add("active");`